# How to fix Error: Os { code: 1, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Operation not permitted" }?

Tags: debugging

When making source code changes in main.rs (Rust), the changes are no longer recognized when I compile.

When I try to debug I get: Error: Os { code: 1, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Operation not permitted" } ?

git source control is enabled
Could this be caused by all my files being untracked in git? (wild guess)

My launch .json file is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "(Ubuntu Linux)Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/chess-on-tap",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there were "orphan" debug and release folders for my project generated outside my project folder because I set $CARGO_TARGET_DIR to the wrong target folder.

Somehow my project in VSCode got corrupted by this.

Solution:

1- set $CARGO_TARGET_DIR to the correct target folder of my project folder

2- delete orphan folders

3- save config files and main.rs (and any other source files) to a different temp folder

4- delete the project folder

5- create a new rust project folder

6- repopulate new project with config and source files from temp folder